# linefeed character reading in java

Tags: java, carriage-return, linefeed

I am wondering that when I open a file in notepad. I see a continuous line without any carriage return/line feed.

I made a java program to read the file. When I split the data from file by using `\n` or `System.getProperty("line.separator");`. I see lots of lines.

I found in hex editor that file has '0A' for new line ( used in UNIX ) and it appears as a rectangle in Notepad.

Well, my question is that if it doesn't have '0D' and 'OA' ( used in Windows for carriage return and line feed ). How my java program is splitting the data into lines? It should not split it.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java internally works with Unicode.

> The Unicode standard defines a large number of characters that
>   conforming applications should recognize as line terminators:[3]
>   LF: Line Feed, U+000A
>   VT:    Vertical Tab, U+000B
>   FF:    Form Feed, U+000C
>   CR:    Carriage Return, U+000D
>   CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)
>   NEL:   Next Line, U+0085
>   LS:    Line Separator, U+2028
>   PS:    Paragraph Separator, U+2029

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)
That's why it interprets `\n` as newline.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right. `"123\n456".split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))` is an array of size 1 on Windows.

Comment: String's split method accepts a regular expression where `\r\n` doesn't match `\n` but in a `JTextArea` the line breaks should render fine - same should apply for `System.out.print`.

Comment: This is what documented in Java's Buffered reader readline() method : Read a line of text.  A line is considered to be terminated by any one
     * of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
     * followed immediately by a linefeed.

Answer (score 2):

The character `\n` is `0a` (carriage return). If you split Windows line separators by `\n` only you'll split on the `0a`, leaving the `0d` characters behind.

Notepad shows `0a` as a square, but it will render `0d0a` as a newline.

Here's an example using Scala (it's Java under the covers) on Windows:

```
scala> "123\n456".split(System.getProperty("line.separator")).length
res1: Int = 1

scala> "123\n456".split("\r\n").length  // same as the line above on Windows
res2: Int = 1

scala> "123\n456".split("\n").length
res3: Int = 2
```

Comment: exactly, for windows new line, you would split it by "\r\n" , not just "\n"

Answer (score 0):

Windows Notepad is something to be strongly avoided when dealing with any type of text file.
I suggest using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Not only he'll display your text nicely, but it also has a feature to encode the file in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and without [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) :D